# How to return an ArrayList from a WebService in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, object, arraylist

I have been trying to return an ArrayList from a WebService and I am confused about how to get it going as I get an error message saying

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'".

Here is the Code for the Web Service names DDRParserService.asmx .

```
public ArrayList PVTLog(string reqNo, string groupNo, string filePath)
{
ArrayList logData = new ArrayList();

//Calling the Parsing Logic file
logData = ParsePVTLog_Service(reqNo, groupNo, filePath); 

// I get the ArrayList in logData and return it
return logData

}
```

The Code where I consume the Web Service:

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strFilePath = txtOpenFile.Text;
  string serialNo = txtSerialNumber.Text;
  string groupNo = txtGroupNumber.Text;
  ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

  if (txtOpenFile.Text != "")
    {
      DDRParsingService.DDRParserService client = new DDRParsingService.DDRParserService();

      // Call the Web Service
     data =  client.PVTLog(serialNo, groupNo, strFilePath);
      // I get the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'          
    }

}
```

It would be great if you can help me handle this issue and access the data in the ArrayList returned by the Web Service.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'd recommend using a generic `List<T>` over an `ArrayList` ....

Comment: I  found a solution!!  ....while consuming the Web Service, I can do this :  ArrayList data = new ArrayList(client.PVTLog(serialNo, groupNo, strFilePath)); ..it works!!

Answer (score 1):

on your service reference click configure:
[image]

Select your expected collection type:

[image]

click OK, then update the service reference:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. ..What if I have the Service Reference as a Web Reference ?

Answer (score 0):

When calling the Web Service, all I had to do was declare the returned object from the Web Service as a new ArrayList.

In the above code that I have posted, I called the Web Service like this :

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strFilePath = txtOpenFile.Text;
  string serialNo = txtSerialNumber.Text;
  string groupNo = txtGroupNumber.Text;
  ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

  if (txtOpenFile.Text != "")
    {
      DDRParsingService.DDRParserService client = new DDRParsingService.DDRParserService();

      // Call the Web Service
     data =  client.PVTLog(serialNo, groupNo, strFilePath);
      // I get the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'          
    }

}
```

But all I had to do was this :

`data =  new ArrayList(client.PVTLog(serialNo, groupNo, strFilePath));`

i.e. Declare the returned object[] from the Web Service as a new ArrayList!